# Find out size of all data ever downloaded

Tags: data-monitoring

Is somehow possible to find out size of all data I ever downloaded on my HTC phone?

edit:source from which I downloaded data will be also super

Thanks

Comment: what service provider do you have?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: If it's a sprint phone, you can get this information on their website, or by calling #4. This won't get you sources of downloads, but they keep data traffic records for a year.

Answer (score 1):

Your carrier would keep track of how much you've downloaded over 3G.  I highly, highly doubt they do enough logging to tell you where all of it came from though (and if they did, they'd probably make you pay to access the logs if they let you at all).

There's no way to tell exactly what you've downloaded over WiFi, apart from browser history for file downloads if you've never cleared the list.  Presumably you could modify Android to log everything, but as far as I know it hasn't been done up till now.

Answer (score 1):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198751/how-do-you-find-out-how-much-data-has-been-transferred-over-wifi-3g-or-edge-on-a) on Stack Overflow says you can find this info through the API - `android.net.TrafficStats`, or `/sys/class/net/statistics` on pre-2.2 systems. This might help you, I hope.

I wonder what happened to the widget that question's poster was writing...

Comment: Newer versions clearly do have this facility, eh?

Comment: For newer Android versions you can use the [android.net.TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class.

Comment: For new versions you can just go to Settings->Data Usage and wind the start time back from the default of last month to the beginning of time.